# Limited network transfer speeds

Tags: 12.10, networking, apache2

I'm running ubuntu Server 12.10 I have apache installed on both the ubuntu server and a virtualbox windows server running on the ubuntu as a guest. However When I download files from my webserver the rates go down to 200kbps This happens on both the ubuntu server and the Windows server. It's as if something is limiting the network speeds for apache in specific. Our minecraft server on the network doesn't lag and gets great speeds we did speedtest.net and came out with 70mbps download and 44mbps upload. What could be limiting my network speeds?

Last packages I installed before this happened Virtualbox and VMWare and I removed VMWare

Comment: Could you elaborate as to which webserver you're referring to?  Is it Apache running on Ubuntu, or on virtual windows host?  Also, anything look odd in the apache logs?

Comment: Both have this bug. It never did this before on just ubuntu. But either one will run slow transfer speeds

Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Try downloading the data from the physical host to the virtual host over the webserver, what are the speeds like there?

Comment: they're the same. but it only does this when I download files It did this for IIS in windows too

Comment: how quickly can you copy the actual files on the filesystem?  I.e. # cp -r /path/to/site-root /tmp  I ask because if the filesystem is struggling with IO, that'd be an obvious sign of why it seems the network is bottlenecked.  Also, you should try to curl/wget a large file outside of your server, just to make sure the bottleneck isn't on the host itself.  It could be something as simple as bad settings on the network device.

Comment: pretty fast it's just as it normally would be